# Autofilter multiple columns, copy and paste a specific visible cell to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I want to apply autofilter to multiple columns in a Master_sales_2022 worksheet (called ws_copy) and copy only column D of ws_copy to paste in column I of ws_paste. However, VBA always shows an error in this line which I am now struggled with fixing this bug

```
.Range("D2:D15009" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Below is my code:

```
Sub Yes_No_Filter()
    
    Dim ws_copy As Worksheet
    Dim ws_paste As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    Set ws_copy = Workbooks("Master_sales_2022.xlsm").Sheets("Master")
    Set ws_paste = Workbooks("2022_Summary.xlsm").Sheets("Summary")

    
    With ws_copy
      
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
   
    End With
       
    With ws_paste
        
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   
    End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
   
    With ws_copy
    
        If .Cells(i, 14).Value = "Yes" Then                 
           
            .Range("A1:EH15009").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="202207"
            .Range("A1:EH15009").AutoFilter Field:=92, Criteria1:=.Cells(i, 2)
            .Range("A1:EH15009").AutoFilter Field:=93, Criteria1:=.Cells(i, 3)
            .Range("A1:EH15009").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=.Cells(i, 4)
            .Range("A1:EH15009").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=.Cells(i, 11)
            .Range("D2:D15009" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            ws_paste.Range("I" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
            ws_copy.AutoFilterMode = False


            
            j = j + 1
            
            
        End If
                
    End With
    
   Next i
   
End Sub
```

Comment: When `LastRow` gets to 10, your range would be `.Range("D2:D1500910")` - which is beyond the bounds of the sheet. What are you trying to achieve with that range?

Comment: `.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`